# read_csv в pandas неправильно обрабатывает целочисленные и десятичные числа из CSV файла

Tags: python, pandas, csv

После этого кода:

```
import locale
    import sys
    from locale import atof
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')
    'en_GB.UTF-8'
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
    from sklearn import metrics 

col_names = ['Project', 'OrderDate', 'orderid', 'ClientID','IsRepeat','IsBlocked','IsManual','AutoDecision','ManualApprove','IsLoan','ShortTermAmount','ShortTermPeriod','LongTermAmount','LongTermPeriod','RequestedAmount','RequestedPeriod','LoanSum','Period','ShortTermScore','LongTermScore']
dtypes={"Project": bool, "OrderDate": 'str', "orderid": "Int64", "ClientID" : "Int64","IsRepeat" :bool,"IsBlocked":bool,"IsManual":bool,"AutoDecision":bool,"ManualApprove":bool,"IsLoan":bool, "ShortTermAmount":"Int64","ShortTermPeriod":"Int64","LongTermAmount":"Int64","LongTermPeriod":"Int64","RequestedAmount":"Int64","RequestedPeriod":"Int64","LoanSum":"Int64","Period":"Int64","ShortTermScore":"float64","LongTermScore":"float64"}
parse_dates = ['OrderDate']
test = pd.read_csv("/home/man/Test_task.csv",sep=' , ', thousands=',', header=None, names=col_names, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates, converters = {'Project': lambda x: bool(str(x)) if x != '-' else np.nan, 'IsRepeat': lambda x: bool(str(x)) if x != '-' else np.nan, 'IsBlocked': lambda x: bool(str(x)) if x != '-' else np.nan, 'IsManual': lambda x: bool(str(x)) if x != '-' else np.nan, 'AutoDecision': lambda x: bool(str(x)) if x != '-' else np.nan, 'ManualApprove': lambda x: bool(str(x)) if x != '-' else np.nan, 'IsLoan': lambda x: bool(str(x)) if x != '-' else np.nan})
df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
test.head()
```

с данными из этой csv - таблицы:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Oseh4KnE98tC3-jRyqWI2Ogr6usoOlvd/view

у меня заголовок таблицы печатается, но потом, при попытке подействовать на элементы таблицы как на числа, получаю ошибку, что нельзя действовать так на строки, при том, что pandas распознаёт dtype всех колонок как "object", а, судя по всему, вообще как "str".

Неужели в таблице есть какие-то скрытые символы и она испорчена?

UPDATE: по совету MaxU, я добавил обрамляющие пробелы в sep. Стало лучше, колонки LoanSum, Period, ShortTermScore, LongTermScore наконец-то стали распознаваться как float64, однако, теперь в этих колонках вместо чисел стоят NaN, и другие числовые колонки все также имеют тип object(хотя и с правильными числами).

Comment: у вас разделитель данных - запятая, обрамленная пробелами...

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду. В CSV файле ошибочное форматирование?

Comment: я имею ввиду, что вы используете в коде табуляцию (`sep='\t'`) в качестве разделителя полей, а в CSV файле используется другой разделитель...

Comment: Я немного изменил вопрос на актуальный

Comment: Я прочитал ваше сообщение ещё раз, и добавил обрамляющие пробелы в sep. Стало лучше, колонки LoanSum, Period, ShortTermScore, LongTermScore наконец-то стали распознаваться как float64, однако, теперь в этих колонках вместо чисел стоят NaN. И другие числовые колонки все также имеют тип object